# Highcharts - Plot bands break zoomType scrubbing after legend toggle

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I noticed some strange behavior when using plotBands in conjunction with legend toggles in highcharts:

To reproduce:

```
    1. Toggle off both series
    2. Select an arbitrary x area
    3. Turn the series back on
```

With plot bands - http://jsfiddle.net/EqC2k/

Now try without plot bands - http://jsfiddle.net/pQvr6/

Notice how the areas are no longer stacked in the example with plot bands.

Opening the console reveals:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'complete' of undefined
```

I have a potential fix for it, but I was wondering if there was a recommended way for dealing with this?

Comment: It's already fixed on master branch: http://jsfiddle.net/EqC2k/2/